# PHPUnit assertTrue Issue

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit to test my code But when i use assertTrue phpunit behaves expectly. Is this normal beahviour of phpunit or not. I got the following error.

Failed asserting that 1 is true.

Comment: Post your code... And you will get answers...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 is not a "real" true value. You can try this :

```
true == 1 // return true
true === 1 // return false
false == null // return true
false === null // return false
```

PHPUnit use `===` in `assertTrue`. So if you do `assertTrue(1);`, PHPUnit just stop because the assertion is false.